# How to get array of different dimensional multiple arrays in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am constructing graph data. Therefore I generated 3 different matrix like `adjacency_matrix, Node_labels, & Adj_joint_matrix`.

```
adjacency_matrix.shape = (4,4)
Node_labels.shape = (4,1)
Adj_joint_matrix.shape = (4,3)
```

At that time, I want to merge these three multidimensional arrays into one common array called `graph_struct`. I tried

```
graph_struct = np.asarray([adjacency_matrix],[Node_labels],[Adj_joint_matrix]) 
graph_struct = np.array([adjacency_matrix],[Node_labels],[Adj_joint_matrix]).
```

But it doesn't give the solution.

output should like:

```
graph_struct = array([adjacency_matrix],[Node_labels],[Adj_joint_matrix])
```

Comment: Can you specify he expected shape of graph_struct? Please provide some example of input and expected output.

Comment: Can you use a list?  Why array?  What shape and dtype do you need?

Comment: With that mix of shapes trying to construct an object dtype array with `np.array` raises an error..  There are ways around it, but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [268]: x = np.ones((4,3),int); y = np.zeros((4,1),int)
```

With this combination of shapes (same 1st dimension) `np.array` raises an error:

```
In [269]: np.array((x,y))                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-269-8419f5dd7aa8> in <module>
----> 1 np.array((x,y))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,3) into shape (4)
```

WIth different 1st dimensions, it makes an object dtype array - basically a glorified (or debased) list of arrays:

```
In [270]: np.array((x.T,y.T))                                                   
Out[270]: 
array([array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]]),
       array([[0, 0, 0, 0]])], dtype=object)
```

`np.array` tries to make a regular multidimensional array.  If the shapes don't allow that, it has to fall back on the object dtype, or fail.

We can pre allocate the object array, and assign the elements:

```
In [271]: res = np.empty((2,),object)                                           
In [272]: res                                                                   
Out[272]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [273]: res[0]=x; res[1] = y                                                  
In [274]: res                                                                   
Out[274]: 
array([array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]),
       array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]])], dtype=object)
```

A potentially useful structured array can be constructed with:

```
In [278]: res1 = np.zeros((4,), dtype=[('x',int,(3,)),('y',int,(1,))])          
In [279]: res1                                                                  
Out[279]: 
array([([0, 0, 0], [0]), ([0, 0, 0], [0]), ([0, 0, 0], [0]),
       ([0, 0, 0], [0])], dtype=[('x', '<i8', (3,)), ('y', '<i8', (1,))])
In [280]: res1['x']=x                                                           
In [281]: res1['y']=y                                                           
In [282]: res1                                                                  
Out[282]: 
array([([1, 1, 1], [0]), ([1, 1, 1], [0]), ([1, 1, 1], [0]),
       ([1, 1, 1], [0])], dtype=[('x', '<i8', (3,)), ('y', '<i8', (1,))])
In [283]: res1[0]                                                               
Out[283]: ([1, 1, 1], [0])
```

If the size 4 dimension is put in the `dtype`, the result is a 0d array:

```
In [284]: np.array((x,y), dtype=[('x',int,(4,3)),('y',int,(4,1))])              
Out[284]: 
array(([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[0], [0], [0], [0]]),
      dtype=[('x', '<i8', (4, 3)), ('y', '<i8', (4, 1))])
In [285]: res2 = np.array((x,y), dtype=[('x',int,(4,3)),('y',int,(4,1))])       
In [287]: res2.shape                                                            
Out[287]: ()
```

Practically this is more like a dictionary, `{'x':x, 'y':y}` than an array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use structured arrays. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#.

I assume that type of adjacency_matrix is bool. The other two are ints. You can create a structured array with command:

```
graph_struct = np.array((adjacency_matrix,Node_labels,Adj_joint_matrix),
                        dtype='(4,4)?,(4,1)i,(4,3)i')
```

Remember to put `()` around structure elements to prevent numpy trying to merge elements to a single ndarray.

For inputs:

```
adjacency_matrix = np.array([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]], dtype=bool)
Node_labels = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]], dtype=int)
Adj_joint_matrix = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
```

The output is a structured array with fields f0, f1, f2:

```
array(([[False,  True, False, False], [ True, False,  True,  True], [False,  True, False, False], [False,  True, False, False]],
       [[1], [2], [3], [4]],
       [[ 0,  1,  2], [ 3,  4,  5], [ 6,  7,  8], [ 9, 10, 11]]),
       dtype=[('f0', '?', (4, 4)), ('f1', '<i4', (4, 1)), ('f2', '<i4', (4, 3))])
```

If the shape of your arrays is not known in advance then it can be constructed with:

```
graph_struct_dtype = np.dtype([('f0',(bool, adjacency_matrix.shape)),
                               ('f1',(int, Node_labels.shape)),
                               ('f2',(int, Adj_joint_matrix.shape))])

graph_struct = np.array((adjacency_matrix,Node_labels,Adj_joint_matrix),
                        dtype=graph_struct_dtype)
```

Comment: I tried  graph_struct = np.array([(adjacency_matrix),(Node_labels),(Adj_joint_array)],dtype='(4,4)i,(4,1)i,(4,3)i'). It throws the error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,4) into shape (4)

Comment: replace [] with ()

Comment: Good answers should have a working example.  Otherwise they arely to be buggy.

Comment: @hpaulj, I would like to add a working example but no reasonable input is provided by the author of the question. I am not even sure if types of individual arrays are correct. Anyway, I will provide some example

Comment: sorry for late reply. Thanks @tstanisl for good answer. It solved my problem. One more question is, if I want to change the shape at every iteration, how can I replace for example (4,4)i to (adjacency_matrix.shape)i???

Comment: I tried it, but it shows ValueError: format number 1 of "b'(adjacency_matrix.shape)i,(Node_labels.shape)i,(Adj_joint_array.shape)i'" is not recognized

Comment: @Ben, I've updated the answer to provide a more robust way to construct the dtype

Comment: If I want to access then three arrays, is it possible? like graph_struct[0]=adjacency_matrix. Because right now I am giving tuple of three array and that#s why may be I can't access now. Is there any other way

Comment: @Ben try ```graph_struct["f0"] = adjacency_matrix```. You can select more convenient names in call to dtype().

Comment: can you suggest, how to convert it in form like:             `PTC_graph_struct[0][0]
Out[17]: 
(array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), array([[(array([[ 5],
       [22],
       [ 5],
       [ 5],
       [20]], dtype=uint8),)]], dtype=[('values', 'O')]), array([[array([[2]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[1, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[2]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[2]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[2]], dtype=uint8)]], dtype=object))`

Comment: @ben, do you want an object dtype array, or a structured one?  Don't confuse the two?

Comment: What's the shape of `graph_struct`?

Comment: I want at the end dtype array